# Python Discord.py - Bot wont register reactions to messages from before the bot is started

Tags: python, discord, bots, message

I'm writing a discord bot for a server which I want to detect when someone has reacted to a message. It's working flawlessly for all messages that were sent while the bot is active. Any messages that were sent before the bot came online, however, are not picked up. Almost as if the bot simply isn't monitoring them.

Here is the code I'm using:

> ```
> @client.event async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
> #ensures the message is not from itself and it's in the right channel
> if reaction.message.author == client.user or reaction.message.channel.name != 'basement-bets':
>     return
>
> #calls the appropriate function based on the emoji sent by the mod
> if reaction.emoji == '':
>     outPut = betting.bet_won(reaction.message.id)
>     await client.get_channel(channel).send('{0.author.mention}, '.format(reaction.message) + outPut)
>     print(outPut)
> ```

I've searched the API and I'm struggling to see why this is, or how I widen the scope of the bots view, should that be the issue.

All help greatly appreciated.

Edit: To clarify, I mean that once I turn it on and it's online, it won't monitor the messages sent prior to it being on. Even after coming online.

Comment: When your bot is off, of course it wont be able to monitor reactions since its off

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to handle that separately by retrieving the reactions and parsing them. I don't believe there is any way to queue them (unless you write a service that handles that, but then that service will also "drop messages" when it goes offline).

Answer (score 0):

It Isn't Possible To Let The Bot Be Working While It's Offline. However, There Are Solutions.

Perhaps Try To Host Your Bot on Something Like Heroku, It Will Be Online For about 3/4 of the Month if You Use the Free Plan. (If You Have Trouble Getting It Up, Consider Watching a YouTube Tutorial)

If You Want It To Be Online 24/7 However, Then You Probably Will Need to Pay.

Comment: Thank you for your response. To clarify, however, as I feel I've not phrased my question correctly: The error I have is that when the bot is online, it will only register reactions pinned to messages sent while the bot was online. Any messages that were sent prior to it coming on will not be detected as having reactions pineed while it's running.

Comment: oh, I'm afraid you can't detect them while the bot is offline.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `on_raw_reaction_add(payload)` it can see every reaction happening but you have a payload in input see the code below to get the user and the reaction (doesn't work in DM's).

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.guild_id == None: # payload.guild_id is None when it is in DM's (you can't get DM channel by id)
        return
    message = await bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id).fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    reaction = nextcord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)
    user = payload.member
```

(code from [Monu Yadav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66906230/13262992))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).